# wp.media multiple selection limit

Tags: uploads, media

When I use wp.media dialog , is there a way to limit how many files can be selected when **multiple** option is used?

```
wp.media({
        library:{
            type: "audio"
        },
        multiple:true
    })
    .on("select", function(){

})
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that feature is not officially supported, so there is no easy way to achieve it.

But if you must, then it can be made possible by *extending the `wp.media.model.Selection.prototype.add` function* which is used to add new items to the selection list.

**Working example:** <sub>(tried & tested with WordPress v6.2.2)</sub>

*( You can see the original function/code [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.2.2/src/js/media/models/selection.js#L42) or find it in `wp-includes/js/media-models.js`. )*

```js
wp.media.model.Selection.prototype.add = function ( models, options ) {
    if ( ! this.multiple ) {
        this.remove( this.models );
    } else {
        const maxItems = parseInt( this.multiple, 10 );

        if ( maxItems >= 1 ) {
            if ( this.length >= maxItems ) {
                this.set( this.slice( 0, maxItems ) );
                models = []; // Cancel the selection.
                //console.log( 'single selection (via Ctrl key) sliced' );
            } else if ( models?.length > maxItems ) {
                models = models.slice( 0, maxItems );
                //console.log( 'multi selection (via Shift key) sliced' );
            }
        }
    }

    return wp.media.model.Attachments.prototype.add.call( this, models, options );
}
```

*How to use the script:*

1. Make sure it runs **only after** the WordPress media models (handle name: `media-models`) are loaded. So basically, you can run that script right before you call `wp.media()`, or you can instead run the script once on page load, but as for how, that is up to you.
2. Just set the `multiple` to the maximum number of items that can be selected via the dialog.

   So for example, instead of `multiple: true`, you would use `multiple: 5` to limit the selection to at most 5 items.

Comment: Works like a charm.